# AWS Cognito - JavaScript Authentication Not Working

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

I've been trying to get Google Sign-In to work with Cognito through the JS SDK.  I've been reading the docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html

This below code is in my function that gets run once I get the callback from Google. I have verified that I am logged in through Google and have an access_token.  According to the docs I should only need the role name if the role is configured through cognito so it can automatically figure out the pool id.  Which it is.  The function calls the get and returns successfully.

Now what I don't understand is two things:

1) Shouldn't I see a new identity in my pool in Cognito once the get method is called? I am not seeing any logins through cognito.  When should I see logins through cognito on the dashboard?

2) Trying to use AWS now to reach specific resources such as maybe read an S3 bucket or something fails due to Auth, and that would make sense if issue #1 is having issues.

I am guessing I am missing something simple here since, any help would be appreciated.  I have also looked at this link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html and tried using WebIdentityToken as well, with no success.

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: '<POOL ID>',
    Logins: {
        'accounts.google.com': googleUser.wc.access_token
    }
});

// Obtain AWS credentials
 AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
    // Credentials will be available when this function is called.
    var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
    var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
    var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;

    console.log("accessKeyId: " + accessKeyId);

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

So the issue came down to 2 things.

Just like Scott was saying I needed to use the IdentityPoolId and Logins within the CognitoIdentityCredentials method.

The second was the token from google. Its not the access token that AWS needs, it is the id_token!  So on the google success callback we get the googleUser object, which has a wc object on it, on that which contains a id_token. You use that token on the Logins dictionary and you have yourself a successful login!

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to specify the Identity Pool ID, not the role ARN (as long as you have configured the UnAuth and Auth roles when you setup your identity pool - which is the default). See the example code at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/getting-credentials/

Please let me us know if you continue to have trouble.

Comment: I tried that too, I made the changes to the above code, but that returns a 400 within the JS SDK.  Even if I remove the Logins map, the SDK still has a 400.

Comment: Please provide the detailed error message your seeing beyond the 400. Also make sure that you're using the ID token from Google as shown at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/google/

Comment: its a 400 - Bad Request. But with your comment I was able to dig some more and that helped me find the answer! I will provide the answer below. Thanks for the help scott!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have 'Generate client secret' unchecked on AWS->Cognito->UserPool->YourPool->Apps->Add App
[image]